# Получить данные из таблицы Mysql, присвоить переменные каждой позиции

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице 4 столбца, id, name, razmer, price
в столбцах name и razmer перечень металлопроката, в столбце price - цена.

например:

name - профильная труба,
razmer - 40x20x2,
price - 120,

name - уголок,
razmer - 40x3,
price - 150

вопрос вот в чем, как обратиться к массиву уже извлеченному из базы чтобы получить стоимость какой либо позиции?
Я бы конечно мог создать сотню запросов и присвоить переменную каждой позиции, но считаю, что есть более короткий способ, которого я к сожалению не нашел

```
$mysqli ->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' ");

$sql = 'SELECT name,razmer,price FROM t_price  ORDER BY name';

$result = $mysqli ->query($sql);

//Тут просто выводится весь список

while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != FALSE){
                   $u++;
                   echo $u.". ".$row['name']." - ".$row['price']."<br>";
            }
```

Comment: `$row['price']` вот прям у вас в коде

Comment: эта строчка выведет все цены, а мне нужно получить цену конкретной позиции, например WHERE name = труба профильная AND razmer = 20x20x2, но я не хочу создавать сотни таких запросов к базе, нужно получить один массив и уже из него получать эти данные, возможно ли это?

Comment: Как обратиться к массиву, чтобы получить стоимость конкретной позиции?

Comment: сделать этому массиву индекс, по которому обращаться

Comment: Чтобы получить цену конкретной позиции не нужны "сотни запросов". Нужен один. В который подставляются нужные значения. Учись работать с БД

Comment: Если внимательно читал, то второй коммент и описывает это самый запрос. Под каждую позицию трубы нужен будет свой запрос, и если мне нужно 10 - 20 наименований, то получается, что нужно столько же запросов. Не нужно умничать, нужно научиться читать    $sql = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE name = 'профильная труба' AND razmer = '20x20x2' AND mernost = '6'";

Answer (score -2):

Разобрался сам, не знаю насколько правильно, но работает

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, "", $db); //подключение
$mysqli ->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' "); //вся выборка будет в юникоде
$sql = 'SELECT name,razmer,price FROM zabor_price  ORDER BY name';
$result = $mysqli ->query($sql); //запрос
//переменная не может быть на кириллице
$cyr = [
            'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п',
            'р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',
            'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П',
            'Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я',' '
        ];
$lat = [
            'a','b','v','g','d','e','io','zh','z','i','y','k','l','m','n','o','p',
            'r','s','t','u','f','h','ts','ch','sh','sht','a','i','y','e','yu','ya',
            'A','B','V','G','D','E','Io','Zh','Z','I','Y','K','L','M','N','O','P',
            'R','S','T','U','F','H','Ts','Ch','Sh','Sht','A','I','Y','e','Yu','Ya','_'
        ];

while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != FALSE){
//Транслитерируем и добавляем размер
$poz = str_replace($cyr, $lat, $row['name']).'_'.$row['razmer']; 
$$poz = $row['price']; //тут то и присваиваю нужное имя переменной
}

//var_dump($row);
// array(6) {
//     ["id"]=> string(3) "281"
//     ["name"]=> string(31) "труба профильная"
//     ["razmer"]=> string(11) "10х10х1,2"
//     ["price"]=> string(1) "0"
//     ["mernost"]=> string(4) "6.00"
//     ["date"]=> string(19) "2021-04-05 12:58:31"
// }

// array(6) {
//     ["id"]=> string(3) "282"
//     ["name"]=> string(31) "труба профильная"
//     ["razmer"]=> string(11) "15х15х1,5"
//     ["price"]=> string(2) "57"
//     ["mernost"]=> string(4) "6.00"
//     ["date"]=> string(19) "2021-04-05 12:58:31"
// }

echo 'Арматура 10мм - '.$armatura_10.'<br/>';
echo 'Труба профильная 20х20х2 - '.$truba_profilynaya_20x20x2;
```

Comment: Это всё очень плохо. и ты правда будешь помнить все эти кривые имена переменных? серьёзно?

Comment: а почему нет? в чем сложность, всего 3-4 названия с разными параметрами. Например $truba_profilynaya_20x20x2, $truba_profilynaya_20x20x15, $truba_profilynaya_25x25x15, $truba_profilynaya_25x25x2, $truba_profilynaya_40x20x15. А прямые какие? сократить название?

Comment: прямые - это те, которые в точности соответствуют значениям в БД. тебе надо научиться работать с массивами

Comment: Плюс я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что тебе вообще нужно обращаться к этим товарам по именам

Comment: поэтому я и задал здесь вопрос, но не дождавшись ни одного ответа нашел такое решение

Comment: Будет калькулятор изделий, где будет происходить расчет кол-ва и стоимости материала, поэтому обращаться по именам надо

Comment: что за чушь? как раз в калькуляторе не нужно ни одной переменной с таким именем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122755/discussion-between-dikkiy-and-).

Comment: Не надо никаких обсуждений в чате. Тебе надо научиться работать с массивами. Для этого надо задать **нормальный вопрос**. Если тебе надо вырезать гланды, то такой вопрос и надо задавать, а не "Какой газовый резак взять чтобы вырезать гланды?"

Comment: Ну я так понимаю, что все твои комменты сводятся к тому чтобы до#$%я. Считаю дальнейший диалог с тобой бессмысленным

Comment: Причем даже не с массивами, а с БД. Купи себе нормальный учебник, и через полгодика сам начнешь понимать, что за чушь ты тут нёс.

Comment: Покажите пример кода, где вы будете калькулировать стоимость. С учётом того, что кол-во позиций может динамически меняться от заказа к заказу